# Jquery to insert total of a column onto another column in SPS2013?

Tags: 2013, list, jquery, column

Please suggest the way to get Jquery to perform total of the numeric value in column 1 and insert the output on column 2 in SharePoint 2013 List?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get total of the current view from `ctx.ListData.Row`.

```
var total = 0;
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(item) {
    total += item["column1"];
});
```

Then update the column2 using REST API

```
function updateItem(url, oldItem, newItem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "PATCH",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
            "If-Match": oldItem.__metadata.etag
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(newItem),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Find the details of REST API (for list) [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API).

Comment: Atish your suggestion is what I `m after as I want to update the column 2 field

Comment: So update it using Rest Api. I gave you a link. You can follow it

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear whether you want to write the value to the list or just display the value.

So here is another solution which only displays the value without actually writing it to the list:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(sum, "inplview.js");

function sum(){
    ReRenderListView_old = ReRenderListView
    ReRenderListView = function(ctx){
        var sum = 0
        jQuery(ctx.ListData.Row).each(function(){
            sum += parseInt(this["Column1"], 10)
        })
        ctx.ListData.Row[0].Column2 = sum
        ReRenderListView_old(ctx)
    }
    ReRenderListView(ctx)
}
```